# Render polymorphic form in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, polymorphism, partial

I want to render a form for a comment in a partial called _feed_item.html.erb. This partial is used to display both Products and Requests, both of which have comments. The rendered comments form needs to be specific to which feed_item is being displayed (Product or Request).

I've created a gist to show what i've got so far. Please do let me know if anything is missing.

https://gist.github.com/aclel/82c332d9fd1a193694ef

Currently i'm able to create a link which takes me to the appropriate url to create a comment. This works well.

```
<%= link_to "Make Comment", new_polymorphic_path([@commentable, Comment.new]) %>
```

Instead of having to go to a different url, I would like to be able to render a form in the feed_item partial.